# Maximun no. of diagonals that can be drawn so that all the parts they divide into are triangles?

Tags: geometry

In a convex n-gon (n>4) no three diagonals are concurrent (intersect at the same point). What is the maximum number of the diagonals that can be drawn into this polygon so that all the parts they divide into are triangles?

Comment: Are the diagonals allowed to meet at vertices of the original polygon? If not, you will have problems getting all parts to be triangles when $n \ge 5$ (try a pentagon to see the issue)

Comment: I found this sum in an issue of Kvant (the Russian Maths magazine). Nothing else is specified except what I have already written. But I am guessing that the diagonals are allowed to meet at vertices of the original polygon,

Comment: @Henry Can't you draw 3/5 diagonals and be fine? You could draw 2 of you wanted to and still make them triangles, no?

Comment: The question asked for the "maximum" no of diagonals that you can draw.

Comment: @Soke: If you draw $2$ diagonals of a pentagon, they will be concurrent either at a vertex or in the interior of the pentagon

Comment: @Henry The problem just requires "no three" to be concurrent? I don't see the probelm

Comment: Either way, I assume it means no three are concurrent at the interior -- this is a pretty common restriction in problems like these

Comment: @Henry Ah, so I get the restriction now. It's saying you create the convex n-gon such that no matter what three diagonals you draw, they do not intersect in concurrently somewhere in the interior.

Comment: yes @Soke. That is it.

Comment: My mistake - I missed the $3$ in *"no three diagonals are concurrent"*

Answer (score 0):

Experimenting with small $n$ suggests that the maximum number of diagonals is given by $f(n)$ defined by $f(2n)=3n-4$ and $f(2n+1)=3n-3$.

We show first that no diagonal can intersect more than one other (in the interior). For suppose the diagonal $D$ intersected diagonal $D_1$ at $A$ and diagonal $D_2$ at $B$ with no intersections between $A$ and $B$. Then $AB$ would have to have a triangle on each side of $D$. But its sides would have to be part of $D_1,D_2$ and they can only meet on one side of $D$.

If a diagonal $D$ does not intersect another diagonal (in the interior), then it divides the $n$-gon into two smaller convex polygons (with no diagonals between the two polygons).

If $D$ intersects another diagonal at $X$ (inside the polygon), suppose $D$ is between vertices $P,Q$ and $D'$ is between $R,S$. Then $PXR,RXQ,QXS,SXP$ are all triangles, so each of $PR,RQ,QS,SP$ must be sides or diagonals. If diagonals, then they cannot intersect any other diagonal $D''$ because if they did, then $D''$ would intersect one of $D,D'$. If none of them are diagonals, then the polygon is just a quadrilateral. If one of them is a diagonal then it divides the $n$-gon into two smaller convex polygons (with no diagonals between the two polygons).

So we have shown that if $n>4$ (and the $n$-gon has enough diagonals to divide it into triangles) then it must have a diagonal which does not intersect any other diagonals. Hence we have $$f(n)=\max_{3\le r\le\frac{n}{2}+1}f(r)+f(n+2-r)+1\ \ (*)$$

Evidently, $f(3)=0,f(4)=2$. So $(*)$ gives $f(5)=f(3)+f(4)+1=3$, $f(6)=\max(f(3)+f(5)+1,2f(4)+1)=\max(4,5)=5$ and so on.

We claim that this recurrence implies that $f(2n)=3n-4,f(2n+1)=3n-3$. We use induction. Suppose it holds for $2k,2k+1$.

Then $(*)$ gives that $f(2k+2)$ is the max of $f(3)+f(2k+1)+1,f(4)+f(2k)+1,\dots,f(k+2)+f(k+2)+1)$. The first term gives $3k-2$, the second $3k-1$, the third $3k-2$. Note that have $f(r)+f(s)$ with $r,s$ alternately both odd and both even. Moving from $r$ odd to $r+1$ increases $f$ by 2, whilst moving from $s$ odd to $s-1$ decreases $f$ by 1, so moving from both odd to both even gives a net increase of 1. Similarly, moving from both even to both odd gives a net decrease of 1, so all terms are either $3k-1$ or $3k-2$ and hence $f(2k+2)=3k-1=3(k+1)-4$.

Similarly, $f(2k+3)$ is the max of $f(3)+f(2k+2)+1,f(4)+f(2k+1)+1,\dots$. Here the first term is $3k$ and the second term is $3k$. This time we either move from odd $r$ to even $r+1$ and even $s$ to odd $s-1$ giving no net change, or from even $r$ to odd $r+1$ and odd $s$ to even $s-1$ again with no net change. So all terms are $3k$ and we have $f(2k+3)=3k=3(k+1)-3$.

So the result holds for $2(k+1),2(k+1)+1$ and hence for all $n$.

Comment: so what is the value of n?

Comment: @RaisaBHuda I don't understand. It is whatever you want!